# How to resize and filter the image in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, how can I perform the following 3 steps:

1. Read an image from disk,
2. Resize it.
3. Change brightness, etc.
4. Use it as a file.

I've tried it with [this](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/image) but it still give me the large file.

```
 IM.Image fileImage = IM.decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync());

    var newWidth = (fileImage.width / 100 * 10).toInt();
    var newHeight = (fileImage.height / 100 * 10).toInt();
    IM.Image resizeImage = IM.copyResize(fileImage, height: newHeight, width: newWidth);

    IM.Image modImage = IM.adjustColor(resizeImage,
        brightness: 50, contrast: 50, saturation: 0.0, amount: 1);

    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    File compressedImage = new File('${tempDir.path}/${path.basename(file.path)}')..writeAsBytesSync(IM.encodePng(modImage, level:9));
```